# what is the difference between Template Explicit Specialization and ordinary function?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
void max (T &a ,T &b)
{}//generic template   #1

template<> void max(char &c, char &d)
{} //template specializtion    #2

void max (char &c, char &d)
{}//ordinary function      #3
```

what is difference between 1 ,2, and 3?

Comment: You can't specialize function templates, the effect would be the same as ordinary overloads.

Comment: @AshleysBrain: That's wrong. You can specialize function templates. You only cannot do partial specializations.

Comment: Ooh, that's what I meant.  Thanks.

Comment: @AshleysBrain: But the `max()` specialization in the above example isn't a _partial_ specialization, but a _full_ specialization. As such it's legal.

Comment: template<class T> void max(T &c,char &d) //working fime
 is it partial specialization?

Comment: @user323422: No, that's a normal function template declaration. However, `template<> void max(char &c, char &d)` is a full specialization, since all template parameters are fully specialized. (You can tell by the empty parameter list: `template<>`.) Function template partial specialization isn't allowed in C++. (You are supposed to overload instead, but applying the trick to use class template partial specialization as given by Gregory is better.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. is a template function
2. is a total specialization of the previous template function (doesn't overload!)
3. is an overload of the function

Here is an excerpt from [C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586):

> 66) Don't specialize function templates
>
> Function template specializations never participate in overloading: Therefore, any specializations you write will not affect which template gets used, and this runs counter to what most people would intuitively expect. After all, if you had written a nontemplate function with the identical signature instead of a function template specialization, the nontemplate function would always be selected because it's always considered to be a better match than a template.

The book advises you to add a level of indirection by implementing the function template in terms of a class template:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
struct max_implementation
{
  T& operator() (T& a, T& b)
  {
    return std::max(a, b);
  }
};

template<typename T>
T& max(T& a, T& b)
{
  return max_implementation<T>()(a, b);
}
```

See also:

- [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)
- [Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)

Comment: added gotw links, same as those given by @Michael

Comment: Ah, I was just about to add the "implementing the function template in terms of a class template"-trick to my answer, but yours is much better anyway. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

The matching rules for template parameters subtly differ from that of overloaded functions. An example of what differs can be seen when you try to invoke `max()` with arguments of different tyoes:

```
max(1,'2');
```

This will match the overloaded function, but neither the base template nor the specialization.

Comment: In my initial read of the code, I see no difference in the signatures between the overload and the specialization, other than the template.  Why, then, would `max(1,'2')` not be matched by the specialization?  More specifically, why is `1`, an `int`, converted to `char` in the overload case but not in the specialization case?

Comment: @rcollyer: See the Quote *#66* in Gregorys answer.

Comment: @rcollyer: The simple answer is: _Because the standard says so._ `template<> void max(...)` is the syntax for a template __specialization__; `void max(...)` is the syntax for a function __overload__. The rules for matching overloaded functions are different from the rules for matching template specializations. (And overloads are chosen _first_ and only if a template is chosen, are possible specializations considered.) Why choosing overloads is so much more relaxed than choosing specializations, I can't say. But I guess that, would rules for overloads be made up _now_, they'd be stricter, too.